# How to implement JSDoc-like dynamic comments for my VS Code extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, jsdoc

In VS Code, it is quite handy to use JSDoc comments when writing JavaScript code, as VS Code then provides really helpful intellisense:

[image: JSDoc comments]

I want to implement something similar for my VS Code extension, but have so far failed to understand how this is done. To provide helpful intellisense for my language extension, I have written a bunch of scripts that parse header comments above each function (during the extension build), and add the filtered data to a JSON file. Then, I use this JSON data to provide intellisense (hover tips, autocomplete, etc.).

However, this solution is not dynamic, in the sense that it does not allow the user to provide their own intellisense content by adding these header comments. The extension would have to be rebuilt for this to happen.

So, how can I implement this JSDoc-like commenting feature for my language extension?

Comment: you mean the links in the tooltips? some of these texts can be supplied in Markdown format, but I have no clue how you should format the URI so VSC jumps to the file and line, maybe it is the same format as the [command line URI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls) `vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json:5:10` or just `file:///c:/myProject/package.json:5:10`

Comment: No, I am not talking about the links in the tooltips. I am talking about the hover tips themselves, for example. My question is how can I provide hover tips, and other intellisense features dynamically, based on the comment above a function, like VS Code does for JSDoc comments. For example, if I have this JS function: `function helloWorld(){}`, and I add this comment above: `/*This is a function*/`, then VS Code will provide a hover tip with the content `This is a function`, if I hover on the function anywhere in the editor.

Comment: you have to analyze/parse (AST - Abstract Syntax Tree) the file and notice that a special comment is followed by a function and then create a hover item in your hover provider

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```js
/**
 * Get a user's full name
 * @param  {Object}     user                        The user object
 * @param  {String}     user.firstName  The user's firstName
 * @param  {String}     user.lastName   The user's lastName
 * @return {String}                                     The user's fullname
 */
function getUserName (user) {
    let {firstName, lastName} = user;
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}
```